# how to put Entities into an array Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a to-many relationship, where a `List` can have many `Items`.
I then have a `List` variable, whith the list Entity that I need. No problems there.

The list is a `tableview` and the user can add rows, so when they add a row it adds it as an `Item` relationship to the `List`.

I can then use `List.valueForKey("item")` to get the Items. But the return type is AnyObject. Is there a better way than casting it to an NSSet and then having to go through and grt the values and putting them into an array?
In other words, how can I get the value of all the Item entities and put them into an array ?

Pd: the Relationship is Ordered.

Comment: "How can I cast what it returns to an array" By casting it to an array. You've answered your own question, haven't you? If not, can you explain further what the problem is?

Comment: probably like this `let items = anObject as! [Item]` ?

Comment: @matt List.valueForKey("item") returns AnyObject, and it doesn't let me cast it into an array. Sorry for my wording, what  I don't understand is why it returns AnyObject if if returns more than one object. Is it because I shouldn't be using valueForKey?

Comment: "and it doesn't let me cast it into an array" What do you mean? Does a hand reach out of the computer and stop you? You are still not explaining what you are doing and what happens when you do it.

Comment: @matt List.valueForKey("item") as! [AnyObject] crashed the app. I will edit the question, because I know i can cast it as an NSSet or Ordered set but i was looking for a better way.

Comment: "crashed the app" Do you realize that this is the only time you have used the word "crash"? You still haven't even said it in your question! Yet this is the heart of the matter. I'm just trying here to give you some hints about how to ask a question usefully.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot successfully cast something to something it is not. Casting is merely a way of revealing the truth to the compiler. The implication is that you know more than the compiler does. But you must tell the compiler the truth! If you lie to the compiler, you will crash at runtime.

So, if casting to an array causes a crash at runtime, that's because this is *not* an array. You can only cast to what it really *is*.

Comment: It might help you to read the discussion on casting in my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting